# How to display repositories in hgweb without path "prefix"

Tags: mercurial

I have reccently setup Hg on my server and my hgweb.config contains this:

```
[paths]
repo = C:\HgRepositories\*
```

In the web browser, where it shows all the repos in that directory, each one has a name that is prefixed with "repo". For example `repo/MyProject`

I don't want that. Is there a way just have have all the repos accessible purely via their actual name? E.g. in this case it would be just `MyProject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the alternate `[collections]` syntax that would be done as:

```
[collections]
C:\HgRepositories\ = C:\HgRepositories\
```

Where everything within the rightside value is used as a repository, and has the left side subtracted from the URL.  That value on the left side might need some trimming/tweaking to make it a valid key due to the c:\ -- I don't have  windows box on which to test that.

Comment: ill give it a try. its certainly the strangest syntax i have seen in a while!